# Working with multiple JSONs from API calls in Python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I'm trying to make multiple API calls to retrieve JSON files. The JSONs all follow the same schema. I want to merge all the JSON files together as one file so I can do two things:

1) Extract all the IP addresses from the JSON to work with later
2) Convert the JSON into a Pandas Dataframe

When I first wrote the code, I made a single request and it returned a JSON that I could work with. Now I have used a for loop to collect multiple JSONs and append them to a list called `results_list` so that the next JSON does not overwrite the previous one I requested.

Here's the code

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'key': 'MY_API_KEY'
}



query_type = 'QUERY_TYPE'

locations_list = ['London', 'Amsterdam', 'Berlin']

results_list = []

for location in locations_list:

        url = ('https://API_URL' )

        r = requests.get(url, params={'query':str(query_type)+str(location)}, headers = headers)

        results_list.append(r)      



with open('my_search_results.json' ,'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(results_list, outfile)
```

The JSON file `my_search_results.json` has a separate row for each API query e.g. 0 is London, 1 is Amsterdam, 2 is Berlin etc. Like this:

```
    [
    {
        "complete": true,
        "count": 51,
        "data": [
            {
                "actor": "unknown",
                "classification": "malicious",
                "cve": [],
                "first_seen": "2020-03-11",
                "ip": "1.2.3.4",
                "last_seen": "2020-03-28",
                "metadata": {
                    "asn": "xxxxx",
                    "category": "isp",
                    "city": "London",
                    "country": "United Kingdom",
                    "country_code": "GB",
                    "organization": "British Telecommunications PLC",
                    "os": "Linux 2.2-3.x",
                    "rdns": "xxxx",
                    "tor": false
                },
                "raw_data": {
                    "ja3": [],
                    "scan": [
                        {
                            "port": 23,
                            "protocol": "TCP"
                        },
                        {
                            "port": 81,
                            "protocol": "TCP"
                        }
                    ],
                    "web": {}
                },
                "seen": true,
                "spoofable": false,
                "tags": [
                    "some tag",

                ]
            }
```

(I've redacted any sensitive data. There is a separate row in the JSON for each API request, representing each city, but it's too big to show here)

Now I want to go through the JSON and pick out all the IP addresses:

```
for d in results_list['data']:
        ips = (d['ip'])
        print(ips)
```

However this gives the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

When I was working with a single JSON from a single API request this worked fine, but now it seems like either the JSON is not formatted properly or Python is seeing my big JSON as a list and not a dictionary, even though I used `json.dump()` on `results_list` earlier in the script. I'm sure it has to do with the way I had to take all the API calls and append them to a list but I can't work out where I'm going wrong.

I'm struggling to figure out how to pick out the IP addresses or if there is just a better way to collect and merge multiple JSONs. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results_list` is a list, not a dictionary, so `results_list['data']` raises an error. Instead, you should get each dictionary from that list, then access the `'data'` attribute. Noting also that the value for the key `'data'` is of type list, you also need to access the element of that list:

```
for result in results_list:
    for d in result["data"]:
        ips = d["ip"]
        print(ips)
```

If you know that your JSON list only has one element, you may simplify this to:

```
for d in results_list[0]["data"]:
    ips = d["ip"]
    print(ips)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the IP try:

```
for d in results_list['data']: #this works only if you accessed data rightly..
        ips = (d[0]['ip'])
        print(ips)
```

---

## Reason for why you recieved the Error:

The `key` value of data is a list which contains a dictionary of the `ip` you need. So when you try to access ip by `ips = (d['ip'])`, you are indexing the outer list, which raises the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

---

So if:

```
results_list= [
    {
        "complete": True,
        "count": 51,
        "data": [
            {
                "actor": "unknown",
                "classification": "malicious",
                "cve": [],
                "first_seen": "2020-03-11",
                "ip": "1.2.3.4",
                "last_seen": "2020-03-28",
                "metadata": {
                    "asn": "xxxxx",
                    "category": "isp",
                    "city": "London",
                    "country": "United Kingdom",
                    "country_code": "GB",
                    "organization": "British Telecommunications PLC",
                    "os": "Linux 2.2-3.x",
                    "rdns": "xxxx",
                    "tor": False
                },
                "raw_data": {
                    "ja3": [],
                    "scan": [
                        {
                            "port": 23,
                            "protocol": "TCP"
                        },
                        {
                            "port": 81,
                            "protocol": "TCP"
                        }
                    ],
                    "web": {}
                },
                "seen": True,
                "spoofable": False,
                "tags": [
                    "some tag",

                ]
            }...(here is your rest data)
         ]}]
```

to get all IP addresses, run:

```
ip_address=[]
# this works only if each result is a seperate dictionary in the results_list
for d in results_list:
    ips = d['data'][0]['ip']
    ip_address.append(ips)
    print(ips)
#if all results are within data
for d in results_list[0]['data']:
    ips = d['ip']
    ip_address.append(ips)
    print(ips)
```